# What is the best practice when an automated test fails because of an open bug?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation

- Keep it on failing till the time bug get fixed(but this will fail
  your test run each time).
- Comment the test and mention in the bug itself(once bug fixed remove
  comments).
- Maintain a bug file(like config) in the framework which skip the
  automated test if it's name mentioned in the file(this is I'm doing right now).

Please suggest.

Comment: You should never have a broken code base (maybe if you have a one-man team but never with multiple people). So only your first option is feasible.

Comment: First option wins by excluding others two.

Comment: If you have a bug - your test should fail - and it will fail until bug is fixed.

Comment: first. all the other options make you ignore and forget the bug

Comment: There are a few answers on SQA:  https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3874/how-to-deal-with-automated-test-cases-that-always-fail

Answer (score 2):

It is a good question. This is why I love `Arquillian` frameworks. As you use `java` , you should totally check this framework.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automation-using-arquillian-framework/

http://www.testautomationguru.com/arquillian-graphene-page-fragments/

http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-managing-selenium-grid-infrastructure-using-arquillian-cube/

Arquillian has an extension called 'Governor' which has a nice feature to skip/execute a testcase by checking the status of an issue using JIRA API. They also support few other bug tracking system. not just JIRA.

https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-governor

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@RunAsClient
public class TestCase
{
    @Test
    @Jira("ARQ-1907")
    public void test()
    {
        // this test will be run
        // because ARQ-1907 is 'Done'
        // so we assume that this test has to pass as well
    }

    @Test
    @Jira("ARQ-5000")
    public void test2()
    {
        // when this JIRA exists and its status is 'Unresolved' / 'Open'
        // this test method will be skipped because you assume that
        // if you run it, it would fail
    }

}
```